# Date String from php to postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql-9.2

my client is proving me with date strings as follows

```
Tue Nov 30 00:00:00 GMT+0400 1965
```

how can i insert this format into a postgresql Date column please, or will i have to do it the hard way and use the sub strings to compile a string of

```
Nov 30 1965
```

Please can someone help im  very stuck for time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible for you, if you date have no timestamp in it:

```
select to_timestamp('Tue Nov 30 00:00:00 1965', 'DY Mon DD HH24:MI:SS YYYY')
```

So I think you have to make a new from your string:

```
select
    to_timestamp(substring(dt from 0 for 20) || substring(dt from 29), 'DY Mon DD HH24:MI:SS YYYY')
from (select 'Tue Nov 30 00:00:00 GMT+0400 1965'::text as dt) as a
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/1428)

Answer (score 0):

ive managed it this way

```
function dateStringToDb($dateString){
    if($dateString != NULL){
        $dateString = substr($dateString,4,6)." ".substr($dateString,sizeof($dateString)-5,4);
        return new Zend_Db_Expr("to_date('".$dateString."', 'Mon DD YYYY')");
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

this seems to be the best method, thanks anyway